# Package is deleted at NMP install

Tags: node.js, npm, build, npm-install, package.json

**Problem:**

- Package Now-UI-kit folder is deleted as soon as I run 'npm install' **or** if I install a package via 'npm install [package name]'

I have a development environment with a build tool for the development of my site. The environment has the Bootstrap framework and a lay-out kit: Now-UI-Kit. This is a template I bought. Based on the documentation of Now-UI-kit I have to run 'npm install' from the folder where the kit is installed. One folder up is node_modules. Below a tree, seen from the node_modules folder:

```
➜  node_modules git:(master) ✗ tree -L 2
.
├── bootstrap
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── dist
│   ├── js
│   ├── package.json
│   └── scss
├── cookies-eu-banner
│   ├── Gulpfile.js
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── bower.json
│   ├── css
│   ├── demo
│   ├── dist
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
├── dyscrollupjs
│   ├── Gruntfile.js
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── jquery
│   ├── AUTHORS.txt
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── bower.json
│   ├── dist
│   ├── external
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
├── jquery_lazyscript
│   ├── jquery.lazyscript.js
│   ├── jquery.lazyscript.js.map
│   ├── jquery.lazyscript.min\ kopie.js
│   ├── jquery.lazyscript.min.js
│   └── jquery.lazyscript.min.js.map
├── now-ui-kit-pro
│   ├── CHANGELOG.md
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── assets
│   ├── docs
│   ├── examples
│   ├── gulpfile.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── nucleo-icons.html
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── presentation.html
│   └── sections.html
├── popper.js
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js.flow
│   └── package.json
├── rellax
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── bower.json
│   ├── css
│   ├── demo.html
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── rellax.js
│   ├── rellax.min.js
│   └── tests
├── resize_header
│   └── resize_header_logo.js
├── scripts
│   ├── jquery.lazyscript.min.js
│   ├── lazyload.js
│   └── rellax_parameters.js
└── social
    ├── changed\ -\ social.js
    ├── defer.js
    └── social.js
```

The latest version of the Now-UI-kit I downloaded from the builder is v 1.2.2 and the latest version on npm is v1.1.0 [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/now-ui-kit)

A snippet from the package json in the src-folder (one folder higher than node_modules)

```
"dependencies": {
 "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
 "cookies-eu-banner": "^1.2.14",
 "dyscrollupjs": "^2.0.0",
 "jquery": "^3.3.1",
 "now-ui-kit-pro": "^1.2.2",
 "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
 "rellax": "^1.7.2"
 },
```

The package json from the Now-UI-kit contains:

```
{
 "name": "now-ui-kit-pro",
 "description": "Premium Bootstrap 4 Now UI Design",
 "version": "1.2.2",
 "homepage": "http://creative-tim.com/product/now-ui-kit-pro",
 "author": "Creative Tim",
 "license": "Creative Tim License <www.creative-tim.com/license>",
 "devDependencies": {
   "gulp": "^4.0.0",
   "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
   "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
   "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
   "gulp-open": "^3.0.1",
   "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
   "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4"
    }
  }
```

Constantly restoring the backup of the Now-UI-kit folder is quit cumbersome and is error sensitive. I recently started with using package, and for this problem, I'd like to understand how I kan solve the problem. I did do a search on Stackoverflow and found some suggestions which I did try, but no luck yet.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi! Where do you install `now-ui-kit-pro` from? NPMJS seems not to know it: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=now-ui-kit-pro

Comment: Hi. Copied the files, these are behind a wallet (?), from the supplier of the kit. Since it’s the pro-version it comes with a license file.